# How to show details about branch in google map?

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I want to show details about bank branch in google map . I make a marker by taking latlng , need to show details about bank branch in  bottom of google map . Is there any good tutorials ?

Comment: Try this link for Infowindows https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show details about bank branch in google map InfoWindow but in top of marker not in bottom of google map.

visit this link:
http://androidfreakers.blogspot.in/2013/08/display-custom-info-window-with.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use InfoWindow to show dta about your marker (branch)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows